# How to use __slots__ in python?

Tags: python

Does this method will save memory significantly when you need to create lots of objects. I read a blog talking about `__slots__` use case, he said that. I tried to test it using memory record lib in my own computer, but I can't find any difference.

Comment: Thanks for your information